# How to define constants in controllers?

Tags: php, symfony, constants

I want to use constants in symfony2 controllers. This is how i am defining them:

```
class MyController extends Controller {
  const CONSTANT_ONE = 1;
  const CONSTANT_TWO = 2; }
```

Is this the correct way? And how do i need to use the constants in the controller? Any other better way?

Thank You!

Comment: I need to use them in a switch statement inside the same controller. I felt using numbers in the switch case (like case 1: , case 2:) is a bad practice. So thought of using constants. Is this a right practice in Symfony?

Comment: If it's in the same controller (i.e. the same class), then yes, using constants is a good idea, since you'll be able to change the switch values (even if you won't probably need to).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your method shown is the correct way to define class constants.  Just basic php programing. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Use a class constant within a class with:

```
echo self::CONSTANT_TWO;
```

Should you be using class constants in a controller?  Probably not.  Consider answering @allessandro1997's question.